# What option need to be selected on product setup page on Facebook application to get User Friends, Likes, Comments and etc

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

What option (either Facebook login or Open Graph) need to be selected on product setup page on Facebook application to get User's Friends, Likes, Comments and etc while creating Facebook application.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

For getting user data, you need Facebook Login. Go to the "Settings" tab and add the platform of your choice - for example, "Website". And then implement the login process: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login

Here is an example of a login process with the JavaScript SDK: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-javascript-sdk-login/ - you